# Not able to recieve the messages RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika, rabbitmq-exchange

I am following tutorial 4 ([Routing](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-python.html)). Following is the code for send.py

```
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='direct_logs',
                         type='direct')

severity = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else 'info'
message = ' '.join(sys.argv[2:]) or 'Hello World!'


channel.basic_publish(exchange='direct_logs',
                      routing_key=severity,
                      body=message)
print(" [x] Sent %r:%r" % (severity, message))
connection.close()
```

and below is the code for receive.py

```
import pika
import sys

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.exchange_declare(exchange='direct_logs',
                         type='direct')

result = channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
queue_name = result.method.queue

severities = sys.argv[1:]
if not severities:
    sys.stderr.write("Usage: %s [info] [warning] [error]\n" % sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(1)

for severity in severities:
    channel.queue_bind(exchange='direct_logs',
                       queue=queue_name,
                       routing_key=severity)

print(' [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
   print "Hello"
   print(" [x] %r:%r" % (method.routing_key, body))

channel.basic_consume(callback,queue=queue_name,no_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

But when I am running the scripts I'm unable to fetch any message from the temporary queue. I guess my `callback` function  is not being called. The  codes are taken as it is from the site.

I am running the codes as:

```
python send.py
```

for which I'm getting:

```
 [x] Sent 'info':'Hello World!'
```

And when I run

```
python rec.py info
```

I get:

```
 [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C
```

And else nothing is printed.
I have even restarted RabbitMQ using

```
rabbitmqctl stop_app
rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I get message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the receive.py first

the problem is, rabbitmq will not hold messages that are not routed to queues.

your send.py does not declare a queue or a binding to the exchange, so when you send a message through the exchange, there is no queue to which the message can be delivered

if you run your receive.py first, you'll create the needed exchange, queue and binding

then your send.py will be able to send the messages and it will be routed to the queue for the receive.py to pick up

Comment: Beaten me by 11 seconds :)

Comment: Ok got that one, so it is not our primitive send and receive thing thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

If the code is exactly like in the tutorial, you need to run `rec.py` first and then `send.py`